# I want to make sure certain links do not fetch information until specific text is hovered

Tags: image-processing, hyperlink, preloading

I've got a list that fetches ~5,000 objects from a database and I'm trying to make it so that when you hover a row in the list, it fetches an image belonging to the item described.

Currently it fetches all 5,000 objects at once but I'd rather have them take a second to load than pre-loading them. I'm wondering if there's any way to stop the images from pre-loading?

Currently I'm only using PHP/CSS/HTML, I don't mind javascript or AJAX (mootools is the loader used since I'm using the joomla framework)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "stop the images from pre-loading." If you are running a query can't you just exclude the images? Then use a hover event on each list item that retrieves the image via ajax? Or even after page loads you could just start loading images via ajax.

What exactly do you need help with?

1. Excluding images from initial db query?
2. Not displaying images in your list?
3. Retrieving images via ajax?
4. Displaying images after retrieving them with ajax?

etc etc

Comment: I guess I'm looking to exclude the images from the initial DB query.